# Xamarin - Cannot rename 'Drawable'.No more internal file identifiers available

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Well my experience with Xamarin has not started well.

I've started a course on Pluralsight, Cross Platform iOS/Android with Visual Studio and C# - Part 1, and one of the recommendations is to rename the Resources subfolders to their lowercase equivalent e.g. Drawable > drawable

However, whenever I try to do this, I receive the following error: "Cannot rename 'Drawable'.No more internal file identifiers available"

When I also view the Main.axml I receive "Disconnected from layout renderer - Please close and open the file again" but I think that may be related to the above.

EDIT: The "Disconnected from layout renderer" issue was not part of the renaming issue. However, there does appear to be an issue with the 22.6 android SDK. Please see [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14344/disconnected-from-layout-renderer)

Since I only downloaded Xamarin yesterday, I am running the latest version through Visual Studio 2013.

Any suggestions?

Comment: lol !  I've just started learning Xamarin, using the same PluralSight course as you, and am seeing the same errors !  Also, I have never seen VS2013 crash so much..  this software is a disaster with VS2013..

Comment: This isn't Xamarin specific. I had the same error in normal VS2013 asp.net project. The folder name's case in the solution didn't match its case in the filesystem and that was breaking chrome dev tools' filesystem mapping. Trying to correct it resulted in the same error.

Comment: As mentioned by Tim, the issue occurs when the case in the filesystem does not match the case in VS.  I fixed the case in the filesystem to match the case in VS and was then able to successfully rename in VS.

Answer (score 22):

Take a look at [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5a080fe-cb20-4beb-83fd-3daacee6394c/no-more-internal-identifiers-available-on-rename-of-file?forum=csharpide)

Rename from "Drawable" to "draw" and then renamed to "drawable".
Apparently there's an issue renaming a folder with just a case change.

Comment: This fix also works if you're having this problem with files

Comment: VS 2015 Community still has this bug, thanks for the simple fix

Answer (score 1):

Really there is no reason to renamed the `Drawable` folder, unless you think the folder name looks prettier in lower case. I tried renaming mine to `❤Drawable❤`, but it didn't work either. Your error message seems like a Visual Studio error, so maybe try changing the folder name in the csproj file manually if you really want to do it.

They just put out an update to Xamarin.Android that fixes the issue with the designer for me (but I could only try it on a Mac because I'm not in the office right now): [Xamarin.Android 4.12.1](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_4/xamarin.android_4.12/#Xamarin.Android_4.12.1)

Google released a new SDK recently that broke the designer apparently, and so just some bad luck on that one.

Comment: Hello Mr Peppers. Yeah I didn't think much of renaming the folders. However, I've added a few images to drawing, simply add a source to an image view and when I hit the ellipses, I'm presented with nothing. It doesn't recognize any present images.

Comment: Make sure the build action on all the images in your `Drawable` folder have a build action of `AndroidResource` (find this in the properties window in VS). Then build the project and try again.

Comment: Hello Jonathan. No joy. Build actions set accordingly, built, rebuilt and still no luck in displaying the image. Can't help but think the two things are related..

Comment: Does the image's id appear in `Resources.Drawable.YourImageName`? Can you try making a new project and seeing if it works in a fresh one?

Comment: Yup they all appear in the Resources class along with there constant ints.

Comment: I've started from scratch and the same thing occurs. I might trying removing it all and reinstall as something doesn't seem right.

Comment: I would reinstall, and make sure your Android SDK is up to date in the SDK manager.